# Angular 7: How to keep component persist when user clicked cancel In confirmation Pop-up

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using confirm pop-up to ask user to validate his/her action of leaving page without saving the changes.

In order to achieve this in Angular 7, code is done in this way:

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.updateProfile) {
      if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you wanna leave this page the changes may lost?')) {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/profile']); //Currently navigating to the same page
      }
    }
  }
```

The navigation to the same page looks fine for this type of situation but I'm using the same page for view and edit the details. and when i do redirect it to Profile page by default view mode is opened.

What i want is if user clicked on 'Cancel' Pop-up the No changes take place for the component.

Is there any other ways to achieve the same in Angular 7?

[image]

Comment: If you want to do it in ngOnDestroy then why don't you put an else below the if condition and navigate on the already opened route?

Comment: @AdnanSheikh, the same is already mentioned in the code i.e. If condition is handling the response of cancel and navigating to the same route. but I'm having same page for view/edit and i need to be on edit page when cancel is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way to achieve this scenario - **Use Route Guard.**

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<UserFormComponent> {
  canDeactivate(component: UserFormComponent): boolean {

    if(component.hasUnsavedData()){
        if (confirm("You have unsaved changes! If you leave, your changes will be lost.")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

For More Information You can visit on Link:

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d

OR

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-candeactivate-guard-example